# I want to draw a circle with a exact diameter in illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I'm designing a glass table top and it needs to be a perfect diameter of 36" can I specify diameter anywhere? or even in Photoshop?

I also need to have the file removed from artboard just a transparent background it needs to be just the circle as a eps file.

does anyone know how I can do this.

Thanks

Comment: You do understand that bézier splines can not make perfect circles. Best you can do is about 0.019608% deviation form radius with 4 points (you can get closer with more points)

Comment: Hi Katie, yes you can, geometrically you won't get a perfect circle it will be off but not noticeable, depending in the design you have to do illustrator will be the tool for the job. What will you final output be? Are you using an engraver to render the image on the table top. Will it be a print transferred to the glass top. Alot of the answers you get are determined by how specific your problem is, feel free to share some more information to get an answer that addresses your unique problem.

Answer (score 4):

Select the ellipse tool, left click on your art board and enter "36 in" for both height and width in the dialogue that pops up.

If you truly want a transparent circle with no outline then turn off fill and stroke.

"Save as" an .EPS with "transparency" selected.

About your need for a file without art board, I'm not sure this is possible with an EPS. If the circle on an art board is sent to a printer it will only print the circle. I recommend making your art board 37" to hold a 36" circle.

Answer (score 2):

Take the ellipse tool, <kbd>alt</kbd>+**Click** on the canvas ans type your dimension values in the dialog that opens.